# Access VBA - Error '3075'

Tags: ms-access, vba

I got this error everytime I try to save the text in this field to the database. The code is this:

```
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO Dbase (EB3_30) VALUES ('" & Me.EB3_30 & "')"
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert
```

The debugger stops at the last line and I get this error (I'm going to traduce it because it's in spanish):

**run time error '3075':
Syntax Error (Missing Operator) in query expression "value of EB3_30"**

The value of `EB3_30` is a string of aproximate length 250. As it's in spanish some letters have accents. I also use dots, apostrophes and slashes. Maybe some of this characters cause problems? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apostrophes probably cause problem.
Try this:

```
strInsert = "INSERT INTO Dbase (EB3_30) VALUES ('" & Replace(Me.EB3_30, "'", "''") & "')"
```

Comment: It seems you are true because it happened the same in another text with an apostrophe, I will check out in a while. Thanks!